# How to write the value of key to another key, inside the same map

Tags: sass

I'm trying to write one value to another in the same map.

1. I want to get "default" value of the current map and multiply it to 5
2. I expect to see 5, and it works OK
3. I expect to see 25, but I've got an error: «Undefined variable»

---

```
$map: (
  "height": (
    "default": 5px,
    "media": (
      "768": map-get(map-get($map, "height"), "default") * 5 /* [ 1 ] */
    )
  )
);

.class {
  height: map-get(map-get($map, "height"), "default"); /* [ 2 ] */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .class {
    height: map-get(map-get(map-get($map, "height"), "media"), "768"); /* [ 3 ] */
  }
}
```

Comment: Pleas provide more details and context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default height in an external variable: it is mooooooooore simple ;-)

```
$defaultHeight:5px;

$map: (
  "height": (
      "default": $defaultHeight,
      "media": (
          "768": $defaultHeight * 5 /* [ 1 ] */
      )
  )
);

.class {
  height: map-get(map-get($map, "height"), "default"); /* [ 2 ] */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .class {
    height: map-get(map-get(map-get($map, "height"), "media"), "768"); /* [ 3 ] */
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why it returns an error?

Comment: It just seems to me that the variable declaration has not ended.

Comment: Because you are in that map and when you ask for its key, $map is not still all defined. Another solution is to use `map-merge`: define your $map without 768 key, then add to $map that value (with map-get), and finally use another time map-get to get 768 value, but well, it is a long way and you can resolve it with a more simple solution, I think. :)